# Porting from http to https in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf, iis

I have a problem while porting my site from http to https, expecially while I invoke any WS.
That are the steps I've follow:

1. Import certificate in IIS
2. Change security mode from "Message" to "TransportWithMessageCredential"

I got this error:

```
SecurityNegotiationException: The server certificate with name XXXXX failed identity verification
because its thumbprint ('XXXXXXX') does not match the one specified in the endpoint identity ('YYYYYY').  
As a result, the current HTTPS request has failed.  
Please update the endpoint identity used on the client or the certificate used by the server.
```

What's the problem ?
Could it be a problem of connections cache ?
How can I prevent it ?

Comment: "Please update the endpoint identity used on the client or the certificate used by the server." Isn't that answering your question?

Comment: I'm not an expert in developing .NET, exactly what should I do?